# Can an LED run by harvesting energy from mains hum?

Tags: led, batteries, mains, energy-harvesting

One morning 2 weeks ago I found a green LED in a carpark attached to a deflated ballon. It had obviously landed overnight. I left it there and when I returned in the evening it was still glowing quite brightly. Impressed by the battery life I took it home, cut it from the balloon and put it in a dark cupboard. Then I checked it every morning to see if it was still glowing.

There's no visible battery, just the LED and I assume a battery inside the tiny plastic surround.

It still is glowing, after 2 weeks. Which surprised me. So...

2 weeks running an LED should run down even a sizeable battery. How little energy does an LED need? If it needs so little energy could it be made to run from energy harvested from mains hum?

Comment: *2 weeks running an LED should run down even a sizeable battery* **Why?** What is "sizable"? What type of LED? How much light is emitted? To make an LED "glow" can take considerably less power than making it light up at it's maximum power. Energy harvesting from "mains hum" (what is that anyway?) is a completely different topic.

Comment: If it's energy-harvesting, it's more likely to be from radio waves. But it probably isn't; it's not *that* hard to power an LED for a week or two with a small battery. Especially high-efficiency LEDs don't take much current at all to visibly light.

Comment: The 9v battery in a smoke detector lets the LED blink (infrequently) for years. Out of all common household alkaline battery types, the 9v has the lowest energy content. So even a tiny button-cell battery could easily power a LED for weeks.

Comment: @SolomonSlow The asker calls this "tiny", though. Anything that can pull significant power through near-field coupling with power lines is going to be a *lot* bigger than "tiny".

Comment: Are you sure it's an LED and not some radioactive thing? A picture would help.

Comment: To some people, a battleship is "tiny".  Please give us your estimated or measured size of the electronics enclosure in engineering units (i.e., mm or inches).

Comment: @TimWescott *engineering units, i.e. ...inches*, no, please, spare us

Comment: @Andyaka having had a few radioactive keyrings, they're a bit expensive to attach to balloons and release; they also look very different (much more diffuse, and a colour you don't normally get with LEDs as the phosphor is quite broadband)

Comment: @ChrisH one inch = three barleycorns, round and fat.  What could be more precise?

Comment: @rdtsc that blinking indicator could be on for a few microseconds a minute, so a duty cycle of 1 in 10 million. The circuit to flash it probably uses more average current.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Curiosity got the better of me, so I had a look at how much power you can capture from power line hum.

I built the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foazVc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I get about 16 millivolts RMS across the capacitor.  Since a 10nF capacitor has about 318 kiloohms of impedance, it's pretty easy to calculate the received power and the current.

$$P=EI$$
$$E=IR$$
$$I=\frac{E}{R}$$
$$P=\frac{E^2}{R}$$

In this case, we can use the impedance of the capacitor as R.

$$I=\frac{16mV}{318000}= 0.056 microamperes$$

$$P=\frac{16mV^2}{318000}=0.0008 microwatts$$

That's not much.

If I cheat, and do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f35sTA.png)</sup>

Where the ground symbol means "connected to household ground from an outlet," I get 41mV RMS.

That's still only 0.13 microamperes and 0.005 microwatts.

There are LEDs that light visibly using 0.1 milliamperes of current.  That's 100 microamperes.  That's  1700 times the current I figured for no ground connection, and the LED will need a couple of volts besides.

You could consider a tuned inductor and capacitor circuit, but then you'd need some pretty big parts.  I figured it up, and you'd need a 3180 microhenry inductor and a 3180 microfarad capacitor at 50Hz.  Both are physically large parts, and making one smaller (in value, which also means smaller physically) makes the other larger (both in value and physically.)

Conclusion:

You can't "harvest" enough power in a typical home to light an LED from just the power line hum.

I think it's a safe bet that the LED "throwie" you found is just running from its battery.

---

I found a 3mH inductor that is 8mmX7mmX5mm, and a 3000µF capacitor that is 18mm in diameter, and 22mm high.  Those are the **smallest** ones I ran into on a quick check at digikey.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and calcs. Much appreciated. The LED is still running on its battery, nearly 4 weeks after finding it. I'd have thought it would run down in less than 24 hours.

Comment: Unbelievably the LED is still running on its battery!! It's not bright, but in a darkened room it's enough to cast shadows. When it finally dies I'll open it up to see what battery its using.

Answer (score 3):

Lets run some numbers:

A 2032 coin cell, as typically used in [this sort of thing](https://www.evilmadscientist.com/2009/some-thoughts-on-throwies/) can provide 230 mAh to 2 V with a draw of 1 mA.  [Here](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/2254/4036) are some discharge curves.  So a 2032 cell could provide 1 mA  for nearly 10 days.

[These LEDs](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/leds/1697752/) rated to max 5 mA would have about 10% of their rated brightness at 0.6 mA, which stretches the capacity still further; they could easily last 2 weeks.  They wouldn't be very bright, but this certainly shows that emission is possible over that timescale with small components.  A series resistor would be enough to limit the current.

The coin cell is much bigger than the LED, at 20×3.2 mm (approx 3/4"×1/8"); the LED an resistor could just be a bump on one side.  That would fit some definitions of "tiny".

---

If it is harvesting energy from electromagnetic fields, which I doubt, putting it in a [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) should attenuate the source enough to turn it off.  Wrap it in clear plastic (to avoid shorting anything) then tightlyin aluminium foil, with a pinhole (literally prick it with a pin) over the LED so you can tell if it's lit in the dark.

It will die in a few days whether harvesting or battery-powered, the difference is that if it's harvesting it will come back on again when you remove the foil (possibly not instantly)

Comment: Or even just stick it in the easily-accessible Faraday cage most people have in their houses, aka a microwave oven.

Comment: On the other hand I've run down a 100Ah battery by leaving 2x20mA (appprox) indicator LEDs attached for 2-3 months.

Comment: @Hearth yes, it's unlikely to use a higher frequency than the door mesh blocks even if it harvests RF.  But I was thinking of leaving it wrapped up

Comment: It's still glowing and not diminishing. Even though it looks like an LED, I think it must be Tritium powered. No tiny battery could last over 3 months. Which then poses another question. Is it even legal to put a tritium glow cell on a ballon and let it go?

Comment: Some photos would be good, especially clear closeups with a scale. I've had tritium keyrings before, and they were pretty dim. Holding one in front of a Geiger counter made the signal go *down* slightly because they blocked some of the background radiation, and they'd be hard to smash, so a small tritium-powered light would only really be litter when released. It seems rather wasteful though. Everything like that I've seen has directly pumped a phosphor with the radiation from the tritium; anything else would be much more expensive